# Billboard Transparency in XNA for Windows Phone

Tags: c#, xna, windows-phone, alpha-transparency, spritebatch

Okay so hopefully a simple fix that I'm just not seeing: I'm trying to implement transparency on a Billboard for an explosion, however the sprite stays solid where there is a pixel not defined transparent in the png file itself. I'm trying to change the transparency by multiplying `Color.White` by the transparency (a `float` between the value of 0 and 1)

```
spriteBatch.Begin(0, BlendState.NonPremultiplied, null, DepthStencilState.DepthRead, RasterizerState.CullNone, basicEffect);

Vector3 viewSpaceTextPosition = Vector3.Transform(this.position, camera.View * invertY);
spriteBatch.Draw(Texture, new Vector2(viewSpaceTextPosition.X, viewSpaceTextPosition.Y), null, Color.White * this.Transparency /*Here's where I try to set the transparency of the image drawn*/, 0, new Vector2(Texture.Bounds.Center.X, Texture.Bounds.Center.Y), this.Scale, SpriteEffects.None, viewSpaceTextPosition.Z);

spriteBatch.End();
```

Are there any obvious mistakes? Or is XNA for Windows Phone 7 just incapable of rendering transparent things in 3D?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using `BasicEffect` instead of the built-in sprite effect, I'm pretty sure you need to set the material alpha:

```
basicEffect.Alpha = this.Transparency;
```